# 8051.h error in Keil, simple C blink-LED code

Tags: build, hex, 8051

I'm trying to set up and test an 8051 development board.
I'm using Keil uVision 4, with some code examples included with the dev board.
The included hex file examples upload to the 8051 and work perfectly.

My problem is in Keil, when I try to build a new hex file from the C code, there is an error with the 8051.h library.  I have placed the 8051.h file in the same folder as is holding the LED.c file, and where the hex file is stored.

Error text:
compiling LED.c...
8051.h(29): error C129: missing ';' before '__at'
Target not created

Here is the original blink LED code:

```
/**********
Blink LED
***********/
#include "8051.h"
sbit led=P2^0;
void delay(unsigned int time); 
void main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        led = led;
        delay(40000);
        delay(20000);
        delay(20000);
        delay(20000);
    /*
        led=1;          
        delay(20000);
        led=0;  
        delay(20000);
        */
    }
}
void delay(unsigned int time) 
{
    while(time--);              
}
```

Do I have bad 8051.h files I'm testing, or what fix may be necessary to correct this?
I have tried multiple 8051.h files and a STC_8051.h with the same problem.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: It seems issue with your project settings. Have you selected to add start up file in your project during project creation?

Comment: There are some statements like '__sbit __at (0x91) P1_1 ;' in **8051.h** file. The error information indicates that the error's location is in the 29 lines of '8051.h' file. How about providing these lines for more details?

Answer (score 0):

It may be in the external memory, in which case you have to declare it as external, using compiler specific lines.

(i.e) With `SDCC` it would be something like this

```
__xdata unsigned char * __data led = (__xdata unsigned char *) 0xMemoryLoc;
```

I do not know how it goes for Keil.